# Highlight Selected Row in Xpage ViewPanel

Tags: dojo, onclick, highlight

I am trying to highlight a row of a selected link from an XPage viewPanel. I found this thread >>> http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/xpagesforum.nsf/xpTopicThread.xsp?documentId=A7133FB0A1AFE05185257A8300429810

I tried it but its failing on the dojo.byId(nodeval). I tried to check the value on that but always returns to null.

Any help/direction would is greatly appreciated.
Thanks very much.

Chay

Answer (score 0):

Dojo.byId() is used to find nodes by id, not nodeval.
I don't think every row has an unique id.
Try using dojo/query.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/query.html

Can you post your failing code?

Comment: Thanks for your time Ken! Here is the code  `var rownum = "#{javascript:return rownum;}";    var nodeval = "view:_id1:viewPanel1:"+rownum.substring(0,rownum.indexOf("."))+":viewColumn1:_internalColumnLink"  dojo.query(dojo.byId(nodeval)).parent().parent().style("backgroundColor","red");`  The nodeval is being set. BTW, I got that code from the link I included on my initial post. Thanks again.